# Matching matrices of different size and creating new matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, if-statement, matrix, compare

I have a matrix `A` and `B` as the following:

```
A = [1 NaN 3 4 5 NaN NaN 8 9 10];
B = [2 6 7];
```

Matrix `B` has the same size as there are `NaN` values in matrix `A` (so 3x1 in this case).

I would like to replace the `NaN` values in the same order as the values appear in `B`. So the output should look like:

```
C = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
```

I can replace the `NaN`, if both matrices have the same size. For `T = 10` and `N = 1`, I would use:

```
for t=1:T
    for i=1:N
        if A == NaN
        C(t,i) = B;
        else
        C(t,i) = A(t,i);
        end
    end
end
```

However, I would like to know whether I could compare these matrices and replace the values even if the matrices are of different size? Saying differently, if `A = NaN` take the first value of `B`. For the next `A = NaN` take the second value in `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
A(find(isnan(A))) = B; % store the result of find(...) to keep track of NaN indices
```

[`isnan()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html) is the proper way of determining whether a value is `NaN` (since `NaN ~= NaN`), while [`find()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) returns the indices of `A` where an element is `NaN` in this case.

---

As per @Adiel's suggestion, you can use logical indexing instead to more compactly achieve the same result, provided you don't need the indices of `NaN` elements later on:

```
A(isnan(A)) = B;
```

Comment: Thank you. That's a good point. However, just executing your code would give me "In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.", as A is of size 10x1 and B is of size 3x1.

Comment: @Joe That's odd; `A(find(isnan(A)))` should give you a 3x1 matrix that you can assign another 3x1 matrix to, unless the number of `NaN`s in `A` doesn't match the size of `B`.

Comment: It's better and faster to use here `logical indexing`- just omit the `find`